IS CAN NM message suppression possible in AUTOSAR
My ECU sends NM message default at startup. I need to control this behavior to send only on certain events. Is that possible? I'm using EB stack.

Network Management is usually pretty much specified on its own, when why and what to send in certain NM states. What are those "certain events" you have in mind?
